# SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'

Tags: javascript

In the function below, IE says that ')' is missing:

```
function padZeros(num, size = 4) {
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Probably because IE doesn't really support default arguments.

Comment: is there any popular workaround I can google so I can use default arguments but not cause any errors? without thinking about it, I have built quite a few functions based on a default arguments. The only way which comes to my mind is having a global variants which are keeping defaulted values, then after function execution with ie different argument, setting it back to the original value... I am assuming that there are better solutions?

Comment: You could use `size = size || 4` but it fails on 0 because 0 is falsey. I would try a `typeof` check for undefined: `size = typeof size === 'undefined' ? 4 : size` or something close.

Comment: @AndrewLi, for this particular use, you would be very unlikely to pass in zero. Of what purpose is a number formatted to zero digits? :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The issue is that Internet Explorer does not understand "default values for arguments" - this is ES2015+ and since development for IE stopped a long time ago, there's no way the new fangled ES2015+ syntax will ever work for IE

Try using a transpiler like [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=env%2Ces2016%2Ces2017&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code_lz=GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwIYBMBaBTATnAZwAowQBbAGkQJgC9tEBeRAFgEpEBvAKET8QBuqXNSaJSZANQAiaQG5e_AO4ALGABsGRAgDpNYAOZQViADzU62Dj363RzaQAZpiSdQW2Avor65sUEFwkAgVPIA) for example until IE officially dies!

```
function padZeros(num) {
    var size = arguments.length > 1 && arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : 4;

    var s = num + "";
    while (s.length < size) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: I will celebrate the day Internet Exploder finally meets its demise

Comment: thanks you all for getting involved, out of all the suggestions, I think this one seems to be most providing the same functionality and in the same time it's kind of universal way to fix all remaining code without huge alterations.

Comment: I read that initially as "IE does not understand default values for arguments... try using a transpiler until IE officially _does_", then a wave of relief washed over me when I realized the word was actually _dies_.

Comment: babel (and other transpilers) are really really great - unfortunately they have prolonged the life of IE!

Comment: ahahaha "Internet ExPlOdEr" :D how true... my whole website looks like a bomb detonated with IE 11

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you are trying to run the Javascript ES6 code on non supported IE browser.

ECMAScript 6, also known as ECMAScript 2015, is the latest version of the ECMAScript standard. ES6 is a significant update to the language, and the first update to the language since ES5 was standardized in 2009.

Please go through the below docs for more details

Funtion with default value : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Syntax

Supported Browser Lists : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Here is the update code for  all browsers

```
function padZeros(num, size) {
 var s = num+"";
 while (s.length < size) {
  s = "0" + s;
 }
 return s;
}
padZeros(10,4)/*10 is your num and 4 is your pad size*/
```

Comment: Many Thanks, I will go through the knowledge from the links above.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are trying to run the Javascript ES6 code on non supported IE browser.

ECMAScript 6, also known as ECMAScript 2015, is the latest version of the ECMAScript standard. ES6 is a significant update to the language, and the first update to the language since ES5 was standardized in 2009.

Please go through the below docs for more details

Funtion with default value : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Syntax

Supported Browser Lists : https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Here is the update code for all browsers

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft Edge an d IE is not supported direct pass the value in function. It is consider as Error file, So that we are getting error

Try below code

```js
function padZeros(num) {
    var size = 4;
    var s = num+"";
    while (s.length < size) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    return s;
}
```